# ScrolledText not appearing with tkinter grid layout

Tags: python, tkinter

When using `.pack()` with my `ScrolledText` widget for tkinter the proper box appears with a textbox that has a scrollbar. However when I switch it to use `.grid()` it no longer appears in the window. Just is gone.

Here is what the applicable part of my code looks like:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.scrolledtext as tkst
import tkinter.font as tkFont
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
class Application(tk.Frame):

def __init__(self, master=None):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
    # self.grid()
    self.createWidgets()

def createWidgets(self):
    self.logArea = tkst.ScrolledText(self,
                wrap   = tk.WORD,
                width  = 20,
                height = 8,
                state="disabled",
                name="logArea"
            )
            self.logArea.grid(padx=10, pady=10,row=1, sticky=tk.W)

root = tk.Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

I have a Treeview widget on row 1 which displays fine, just for some reason this ScrolledText widget does not display at all, but worked fine when I was using just pack() before.

Any idea what is wrong?

Edit: I added a `self.master = master` to the **init** and then used `self.master` instead of just `self` within my init of ScrolledText. I am not sure why this fixed the problem and it would be nice to know why this fixed it.

Comment: Please provide a complete MCVE (http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @BryanOakley done.

Comment: That code won't run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This revision, with the class statement added, the Application frame gridded into the root window, and the text box not disabled, works.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.scrolledtext as tkst
import tkinter.font as tkFont
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.createWidgets()
    def createWidgets(self):
        self.logArea = tkst.ScrolledText(self,
                    wrap   = tk.WORD,
                    width  = 20,
                    height = 8,
                    #state="disabled",
                    name="logArea"
                )
        self.logArea.grid(padx=10, pady=10,row=1, sticky=tk.W)
        self.logArea.insert('1.0', 'test insertion')

root = tk.Tk()
app = Application(root)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Sorry, what exactly did you change? I see the `self.grid()` uncommented. Is there anything else you changed? Because when I use `self`instead of `self.master` in the declaration of the ScrolledText it is still not showing.

Comment: The revisions are  what I said: add `class` statement, uncomment `self.grid`, comment `state=disabled` and also insert test text so the text box would be visible.  (Equivalent to Oakley's suggestion of red background.)  The master for anything placed within a frame or subclass thereof should be the frame, not the frame's master.  So `tkst.ScrolledText(self,` is correct.  I copied this from an IDLE editor (3.5.1, Win 10) after it ran correctly, and `'test insertion'` showed and I could enter more into the text box from the keyboard.